# Assign levels to nodes in multi-level sankey diagram where nodes may not have connections to the first level or the last level

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

First, let me start by saying that I've read [How to assign levels to nodes in multi-level sankey diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637306/how-to-assign-levels-to-nodes-in-multi-level-sankey-diagram)

It helps but doesn't fully solve the issue.

Also, in my example code below I use the networkD3 package but I don't need to. Any package is fine with me so long as I'm able to place certain nodes at certain levels in the diagram.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to draw a 3-level sankey diagram where each node is assigned to a "period" or level in the chart. The full chain of links would be something like Period 1-->Period 2-->Period 3. However, there may be cases where a Period 2 node is not connected to a Period 1 node (Period 2 --> Period 3) or where a Period 2 node is not connected to a Period 3 node (Period 1 --> Period 2).

I haven't figured out how to accomplish this on my own. The image below is what I'm trying to produce.
[image]

Below is some code to reproduce the problem I'm running into:

(Note: this is a simplified version. My actual data contains 150 nodes, 5 Periods and many hundreds of links.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

# Create link data
links <- data.frame(source = c("A","A","B","C","D","E","G"),
                    target = c("D","E","D","F","H","H","I"),
                    nlink = c(12,27,10,5,1,5,10)
                    )

# Create node data
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% 
    unique()
)

# Assign periods to nodes
# I don't know how to actually use this to tell sankeyNetwork
# where to place the nodes but I'm including it here to help in problem solving 
period <- data.frame(period = c("Period 1", "Period 1", "Period 1",
                                "Period 2", "Period 2", "Period 2", "Period 2",
                                "Period 3", "Period 3"))
nodes$nodeGroup <- period$period

# match to numbers, not names
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

# Plot Sankey Network
p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "IDsource",
  Target = "IDtarget",
  Value = "nlink",
  NodeID = "name",
  nodeWidth = 30,
  iterations = 5
)
p
```

[image]

You can see here that even though node "C" is a Period 1 node, it is placed with the Period 2 nodes. If I change the code to use "sinksRight = FALSE" as suggested in this thread: [How to assign levels to nodes in multi-level sankey diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637306/how-to-assign-levels-to-nodes-in-multi-level-sankey-diagram) we get the following:

```
p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "IDsource",
  Target = "IDtarget",
  Value = "nlink",
  NodeID = "name",
  nodeWidth = 30,
  sinksRight = FALSE,
  iterations = 5
)
p
```

[image]

Now you can see that the "C" node is with the other Period 1 nodes as it should be, but the "G" node is now over here too, when it's a Period 2 node and should be in-line with D, E, and F (while I should be in the Period 3 level in-line with H).

Is there a way for me to explicitly assign nodes to a specific level?

Comment: You will not be able to do this with {networkD3} alone. The concept of a column or period or whatever you wanna call it is not a characteristic the {networkD3} accepts as an input because it determines a node's horizontal placement algorithmically.

Comment: Thanks @CJYetman, I thought that might be the case. I'm not wedded to networkd3 though as I don't need interactivity or a widget of any kind. I just need the actual diagram. Given that, is there another technique you'd suggest?

Comment: Is there a hacky way I could make a node/line invisible?